# How to declare projects in sbt plugin

Tags: scala, sbt

I have multiple sbt projects in different repositories with always the same project structure:

```
root
  - api
  - server
```

Because of this i have a high duplication of (configuration-) code between my repositories.

My plan is to write a plugin which provides a

```
class CommonBuild extends Build {}
```

which i then can use in my repositories.

The problem is, i can't access CommonBuild (which is defined in the plugin) in the projects which use the plugin.

What's the common way to solve this?

-- UPDATE --

It seems like it has to do with how i use the plugin.

When i do:

```
lazy val myPlugin = uri("/path/to/plugin")
lazy val root = project.in( file(".") ).dependsOn( myPlugin )
```

the Classes in the plugin are not available

but if a do `publishLocal` and simply use `addSbtPlugin` everything is fine.

Is this on purpose or a bug in sbt?

Comment: Actually, where Are you putting the above configuration. is it in `project/plugins.sbt` ?

Comment: yes, in project/plugins.sbt

Comment: Hmm, I know this works (with Build.scala) for sbt native packager: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/test-project/project/project/build.scala